# how can i use exists database(mysql) in django?

Tags: php, python, mysql, database, django-models

my server already had a database, using PHP web server. but I will change it into the Django web server.
It had a model that has to migrate
If I want to use Django then do I have to remove exists database? 
1. The database table column is all same both PHP and Django so I think if Django connects to the database without migrating then it can use exists database but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **db_table** attribute to map your tables with your models and **db_column** to map columns with fields.

References:

- [Model Meta options - db_table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#db-table)
- [Model Field Meta options - db_column](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#db-column)